# best to way to debug flutter ios app in the terminated state

Tags: ios, flutter

I am working on an ios app with voip notifications. It behaves unexpectedly when it gets the first voip notification when it is terminated. And debugging when it is terminated is not so easy. [As far as I know I can only launch it from terminated in release mode.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-14#launching-debug-flutter-without-a-host-computer) What is the best way to see what is going on when a flutter ios app launches from terminated?

1. I cannot get logs printed in release mode using [logger package](https://github.com/leisim/logger#logfilter)
2. Once the app gets terminated in debug or profile mode, it loses connection with android studio or flutter run. Is there a way not to lose connection when terminating a debug or profile app?
3. Currently I am logging messages on firestore but this is really slow to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using console in "devices and simulators" in xcode "windows" tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run `flutter logs` in the terminal